# FROM is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am new to mysql, and I've been trying to follow some tutorials and I ran into some errors

```
UPDATE a 
SET PropertyAddress = IFNULL(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
FROM nashvillehousing a
JOIN nashvillehousing b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
```

here I am trying to repopulate the column PropertyAddress of a with the same column of the same table. But it shows the error " FROM is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'"

I checked other solutions and modified my query to

```
UPDATE nashvillehousing a 
JOIN nashvillehousing b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    SET a.PropertyAddress = IFNULL(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
    AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
```

and it returns

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  30.000 sec
```

can anyone please help me with this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st query does not use MySql syntax, this is why you get the error.

In the 2nd query you must move the condition `a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID` in the `ON` clause.
Also, since you want to update the only the values of `PropertyAddress` that are `null` you should add a `WHERE` clause for that and get rid of `IFNULL()`:

```
UPDATE nashvillehousing a 
JOIN nashvillehousing b
ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
SET a.PropertyAddress = b.PropertyAddress
WHERE a.PropertyAddress IS NULL AND b.PropertyAddress IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that if `UniqueID` is actually a unique id of each row, then you don't need at all the condition `a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID`, since this is taken care of by the `WHERE` clause where the matching of the same rows is filtered out.

Comment: Thank you! This one runs smoothly and it helps me to see the syntex more clear:p

Comment: @Palladio fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

thte and should be a where clause

```
UPDATE nashvillehousing a 
JOIN nashvillehousing b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    SET a.PropertyAddress = COALESCE(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
WHERE a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
```

Or you put into the join

```
UPDATE nashvillehousing a 
JOIN nashvillehousing b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
    SET a.PropertyAddress = COALESCE(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide sample data, but your query has a major concern that there might be multiple matches with valid address for each `parcelId`.  To avoid this, aggregate the table you are matching to:

```
UPDATE nashvillehousing n JOIN
       (SELECT ParcelId, MAX(PropertyAddress) as PropertyAddress
        FROM nashvillehousing n2
        GROUP BY ParcelId
       ) n2
       ON n2.ParcelID = n.ParcelID
    SET PropertyAddress = n2.PropertyAddress
    WHERE n.PropertyAddress IS NULL AND
          n2.PropertyAddress IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that that `WHERE` clause only updates rows that need to be updated.